# ORA-12541:TNS:No listener while connecting to DB using toad, when computer is in domain

Tags: oracle, database-administration

My system is in domain of my company.
 Installed oracle in my system.
 I am able to connect to oracle using sql plus, but whenever I tried to connect through using toad    following error is coming.

Googled and tried with so many solutions, nothing worked.

See listener.ora file

```
    SID_LIST_LISTENER =
 (SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
)
  (SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
)
   )

   LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ASDi303.abc.com)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 )

 DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

In tnsnames.ora,  HOST is ASDi303.abc.com only...

Comment: Toad has a TNSNamed Editor, try doing a `tnsping` from TOAD and see are you able to have a ping from TOAD?

Comment: If you're connecting through SQL*Plus on the same box the DB is on you don't necessarily need a listener. How are you connecting from both clients - what connect string(s) are you using? Have you checked that the listener (or if on Windows, the service) has actually started? The error message may just actually be telling you that is hasn't.

Comment: Listener has not started...
if I try to start it, saying that "The OracleXETNSListener service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not used by some other programs"  @Alex Poole

Comment: There should be a log file for the listener which will give more detail about why it stopped (or didn't start at all). Better than guessing... but does the hostname resolve to your IP address? Why do you say that is in your `sqlnet.ora` - can you show that file's contents too?